# vim search command not working. :N

Tags: vim

I think a plugin broke my default search behavior.

:n works, which is searching forwards, but :N does not, which is searching backwards. 
How can I find out why the :N key-binding does not work? 
So how can I find out where the :N behaviour gets redefined? answer: -> use :map.

Comment: Uhmm, how exactly do you get <Shift-N>?

Comment: Also, what plugin are you reffering to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour is `n` for searching forward (repeating the latest search, to be exact), and `N` for the opposite direction.

Anything beyond that is impossible to tell from the information you gave.

Comment: I want to know where shift-n get redefined. I have a whole bunch of plugins installed.

Comment: @Stephan - There is no shift-N. There is n, and there is N (which is shift+n) ... in any case, they're hardcoded into Vim. If something is mapped them over (for example nmap n dd), then it should show up in :map.